# Two variables whose values change at the same time

Tags: python

I have this code, the value of centroid is assigned to t_cent and then t_cent enters nested for loop and comes out with a new value. The problem is after the nested for loop process, I find that centroid has also changed in conjunction with t_cent, and I don't know why.

```
def Calc_New_cent(centroids, Data):
    while True:
        t_sent = centroids

        for m in range(k):
            for n in range(number_of_features):
                t_sent.iloc[m, n] = np.mean(Data[Data['clusters'] == m + 1]['{}'.format(n + 1)])

        if t_sent.isnull().values.any() == False:
            centroids = t_sent
            break
    return centroids
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't say so, but I assume `centroids` is a pandas dataframe.  When you say `t_sent = centroids`, you are not creating a COPY of the dataframe.  Instead, you are just creating a new reference to the same dataframe.  When you change `t_sent`, you change `centroids`.  You can use `centroids.copy()` to create a new copy, but you should think about whether that's the right answer or not.  It might be more efficient to modify `centroids` in place, assuming you can learn early enough whether that is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The original code was simpler than this but sometimes it returned nan values, so I followed this approach...thank you.

```
def Calc_New_cent(centroids, Data):
    for m in range(k):
        for n in range(number_of_features):
            centroids.iloc[m, n] = np.mean(Data[Data['clusters'] == m + 1]['{}'.format(n + 1)])
    return centroids
```